# Updating large text documents in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database

I am new to sql. When I want to edit a large text document (for a text-editing app) and commit it to the database, does mysql compare the incoming changes to the old data and make changes without overwriting the entire document? For instance, let's say I make the following changes:

```
const oldText = 'a quick fox jumps over the lazy dog'
const newText = 'a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy'
connection.query(
  `UPDATE table_name
  SET text_column = '${newText}'
  WHERE text_id = 1`
)
```

Does mysql overwrite the entirety of the old `text_column` row? This is likely inconsequential for small amount of text, but I can imagine how trying to add one word to a book-length document can take a lot more time than it should. Or do I need to distinguish those insert/delete behaviors on client-side and use `INSERT`, `REPLACE` etc. manually in sql? Like:

```
connection.query(
  `UPDATE table_name
  SET text_column = REPLACE(INSERT(text_column, 9, 0, 'brown '), ' dog', '')
  WHERE text_id = 1`
)
```

Comment: There is no comparison whatsoever. The update command will replace the contents of the fields with whatever you defined after the equals sign. Also, please consider using primary keys so instead of `WHERE text_column = '${oldText}'` you would use `WHERE id = ${rowId}`

Comment: @JorgeCampos So would the common practice be to track the type of editing actions (insert, delete) on client-side then to use the corresponding sql (INSERT, REPLACE, etc.) instead of updating the entire `text_content`?

Comment: *Does mysql overwrite the entirety of the old text_column row?* If new value is completely equal to new value then MySQL won't write anything. Otherwise the value will be overwrited completely. For example, if UPDATE execution diagnostic is *Rows matched: 2  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0* then this means that 2 rows matches the WHERE conditions and should to be updated, the value for one of them is completely equal the old one and hence won't be writed whereas the second value have been changed and it will be rewrited.

Comment: @Akina So in the case of a text-editor app, where small changes can be frequently made to large bodies of texts, I assume it is smarter to use more specific queries (i.e. `SET REPLACE`), So that not every small change requires a complete overwrite of the value?

Comment: *So that not every small change requires a complete overwrite of the value?* Every. Every change which is saved with UPDATE query. Replace replaces in memory. But when the value is updated in a table then complete, not partial, data rewriting is performed.

Comment: @Akina I see, so there's no way to get around rewriting large amount of content no matter how I try to modify the existing string. Unless there's some ways to do it without `UPDATE` (which I don't think there is), rewriting a small part is the same as updating it entirely with a new (albeit similar) value. Though there could be other differences between the two approaches (i.e. memory), but I will do more reading into that.

Comment: You may think about dividing the complete value to reasonable chunks. Of course this adds the work to the client software but allows it to execute UPDATE only for those chunks which were changed by fact. Totally this may improve the application and decrease used resources.